# Rails exclusive relation SQL select

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a problem like this:

Say I have two models, Person and House, where one Person has many Houses, and each House belongs to one Person.

Let's say Houses can be red, green or blue. If it's relevant, assume each person has 1 house minimum.

How can I write a scope on Person to select People who don't have any red houses?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try

```
Person.where(id: House.not.where(color: 'red').pluck(:person_id).uniq)
```

or other way

```
 Person.left_joins(:houses).where("houses.color <> ?", 'red').uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

In sql database case.If your Person table is a column people.
Select people not in the House table with red color.

```
select * from Person where people not in (select distinct people from House where color ='red')
```